# How to avoiding calling redundancy in context of variable assignment?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, oop, refactoring

I offten (like at the moment) come to the point to write c# (or vb.net) code like this:

```
someObject.field_1 = doSomething( 
                            anotherObject_1.propertyA, 
                            anotherObject_1.propertyB);

someObject.field_2 = doSomething( 
                            anotherObject_2.propertyA, 
                            anotherObject_2.propertyB);

// some more field in same schema.

someObject.field_X = doSomething( 
                            anotherObject_X.propertyA, 
                            anotherObject_X.propertyB);
```

**Edit:** anotherObject_1 .. anotherObject_X have same typ; someObject and anotherObject have normaly not the same typ.

The Problem is the expandability and maintainability. New field brings me to write nearly same code with only little differences in object naming.

With encapsulate the logic in doSomething(..) I avoid logic redundancy, but the calling redundancy is still annoying.

Is there a way (for example a pattern or a .Net (4.0) language-construct) to avoid this?

Comment: Is the whole of the other objects has the same type or not?

Comment: @Viacheslav Smityukh: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. If you ask if someObject and anotherObject has the same typ: mostly not.

Comment: is the anotherObject_1/anotherObject_2/.../anotherObject_X has the same types?

Comment: @Viacheslav Smityukh: Now I understand :): Yes, the same typ.

Comment: Is the PropertyA and PropertyB in the each call has the same names? Is the difference only in the filed name and in the instance of the another object?

Comment: @Viacheslav Smityukh: Mostly Yes, a solution having this condition would be ok.

Comment: So you should set an association between field and instance of another object. I don't see another way to do it instead of write a code like following "field = smth". You can simplyfy it by code like has beed shown in my ansver. May be it has another way to solve but I don't see it for this piece of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can encapsulate set operation into different method

```
void SetField(ref int field, object anotherObjectX)
{
  field = doSmth(anotherObjectX...);
}

SetField(ref object.field1, anotherObject1);
SetField(ref object.field2, anotherObject2);
SetField(ref object.field3, anotherObject3);
```

but you still need to add the new line for the each new field

Comment: Good Idea (+1) - will make my code better. I do something similar already for other code and it works fine. Nice that you've reminded me about it. As you mentioned it does not solve the calling redundancy in self. Let see if there come more ideas :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to reduce code duplication/repetition. If know that your target property would always be called "propertyA" and "propertyB", you can easily use reflection and get/set their value as needed. You can pass in your object as well, and manipulate it there with reflection also.

For example, you can write something like this (note: syntax not fully checked):

```
public someReturnType DoSomething(object myObject)
{
  if (null == myObject)
  { 
    throw new ArgumentNullException("myObject");
  }

  var propertyA = myObject.GetType().GetProperty("propertyA");
  if (null == propertyA)
  {
    //this object doesn't have any property called "propertyA".
    //throw some error if needed
  }

  var value = propertyA.GetValue(myObject); //You will need to cast as proper expected type

  // You can retrieve propertyB similarly by searching for it through GetProperty call.
  // Once you have both A and B, 
  // you can work with values and return your output as needed.

  return something;
}
```

Comment: Interesting Idea. I'm not very experienced in using reflection. I often shy it in terms of hard refactoring, but will check it for my concrete code. (+1)

Comment: Be careful the reflection is so slow

Comment: @Viacheslav Smityukh: Thanks for the hint. I'll remember that. Well, luckily the current project is not performance critical :-D.

Comment: I don't think reflection should be used just to avoid an extra call. Not just for the slowliness, even maintainance of your code would soon become a nightmare